# Is there a javascript/jQuery counterpart to .NET's Enumerable.Select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, ienumerable

I have an array of javascript objects, each containing the members "Id" and "Name". Are there any **built-in** way in javascript/jQuery to project this array into another array, for example one that contains only the Names of the elements. In other words, something similar to the [Enumerable.Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891.aspx) method in .NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There's a LINQ for JavaScript project on Codeplex: http://linqjs.codeplex.com/
- Another method is described here: http://www.ienablemuch.com/2011/05/jquerys-linqs-select.html

An excerpt from it is:

```
<script>

// This evil code was sourced from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/761148/jquery-document-ready-and-document-write/761190#761190
$(function () {
    document.write = function (evil) {            
        $('body').append(evil);            
    }
});
// ...evil :p mwahahah


$(function () {

    a = ["jumps", "over", "lazy", "dog"];

    b = $.map(a, function (v) {
        return "www." + v + ".com";
    });

    $.each(b, function () {
        document.write(this + "<br/>");
    });


    i = 0;
    c = $.map(b, function (v) {
        return { v: v, i: ++i, m: i * 2 };
    });

    $.each(c, function () {
        document.write(this.v + " xxx " + this.i + ' yyy ' + this.m + "<br/>");
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the $.map function of jQuery...great stuff! :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your oldarray contains objects that have a Name attribute. The new array should contain just strings that are the names of the objects in the old array. Using Jquery for such a simple task might be an overkill

```
    var oldarray;

    var newarray;

    oldarray.forEach( function(element) 
    {
        newarray.push( element.Name);
    });
```